# Dynamic Programming for Feedback Vertex Set - bounded treewidth

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parameterized-complexity, treewidth

Saw it on another post that there is a way of solving FVS in polynomial time if the treewidth is constant, using dynamic programming?...

If I'm given the treewidth of a graph, how do I solve it in time $tw^{O(tw)}\cdot n^{O(1)}$ ?

thank you very much!

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? What tools do you know for solving hard problems efficiently for graphs of bounded treewidth? Have you looked at similar results?

Comment: I'm trying to find similar results.. couldn't find any.. saw the vertex cover algorithm using tree decomposition but it didn't help me.. I'm not sure what the dynamic programming should look like..

Comment: It's a standard topic. Have a look at [Chapter 7](http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/parameterized-algorithms.pdf) here.

Comment: thanks, I already read that topic.. I'm having a hard time thinking about the dynamic programming over the tree decomposition... thank you again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you already know how to obtain a tree decomposition. Make the underlying tree directed by picking an arbitrary node as the root.

For a node $t$ of the tree decomposition, let $b(t)$ be the bag at $t$ and $G(t)$ the subgraph of the input graph induced by the bags in the subtree rooted at $t$.

In a bottom-up fashion you compute, for all tree nodes $t$ and all $m\leq n$, the following:
The set of all $(P,S)$, such that

- $S$ is a subset of $b(t)$
- $P$ is a partition of $b(t)\setminus S$
- there is a FVS $F$ of $G(t)$ of size $m$ such that

  - $F\cap b(t)=S$
  - for $v,w\in b(t)\setminus S$, they are in the same connected component of $G(t)-F$ if and only if they are in the same part of $P$

So in essence you compute all possible FVSs for subgraph of the form $G(t)$, but at every bag you apply data compression such that you only know how the FVSs interact with the bag.

The running time per $t$ and $m$ is polynomial in the number of possibilities for $(P,S)$. Let $k:=|b(t)|=O(tw)$. The number of possibilities for $S$ can be bounded by $2^k$. For the number of partitions, let us use the crude bound $2^k\cdot k!$. (It can be established as follows: For a partition of $b(t)$, choose an arbitary order of $b(t)$ such that each part of the partition is contiguous wrt. the order. Then, the partition can be retrieved from the order if we know, for each element of $b(t)$, whether the next element is in the same part of the partition or not.) Thus, the overall running time is
$$O(n^2)\cdot(2^{O(tw)}\cdot 2^{O(tw)}\cdot {O(tw)}!)^{O(1)} = tw^{O(tw)}\cdot n^{O(1)}$$

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! But, obtaining a tree decomposition doesn't take exponential time also? thanks again!

Comment: Tree decompositioning is within your time bound. I believe it is $2^{O(tw)}n$. If not, it is definitely $2^{O(tw)}n^{O(1)}$.

Comment: thanks again! so for every node $t$, a subset $S$ of $b(t)$ and every parition $P$ of $b(t)\setminus S$ you're trying to find an FVS F - this one takes polynomial time?

Comment: Yes, for fixed $t$, $S$, and $P$, the remaining work is polynomial in $tw$.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to save only the vertices of $b(t) \setminus S$ in the partition $P$?