# Feedback Vertex Set in graphs with bounded tree width using Dynamic Programming

Tags: graphs, dynamic-programming

What is the subproblem associated with this DP and what are the terms to calculate?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [Dynamic Programming for Feedback Vertex Set - bounded treewidth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141832)?